# Интеграция компонентов React в HTML страницы на Spring

Tags: html, reactjs, веб-программирование, spring

Необходимо в готовый проект на Spring добавить компоненты React. Другими словами, мне не нужен целый фреймворк. Мне нужно в готовые html страницы вставлять компоненты react. Пробовал делать, объявляя в html странице конструкцию вида
`<div id="some-id"></div>`
но ничего не работает. Компонент не рендерится, страница остается без изменений. Мучаюсь с этим уже с неделю.

Comment: То что вы указали, это обычный html. Что бы реакт работал, его надо скомпилить предварительно, это конечно можно сделать на клиенте, но очень не рекомендуется. Сами по себе компоненты реакта вне реакт приложения, работать не будут.

Comment: К страницам `html` без "целого фреймворка" Реакт не подключить... Вот как это делается - https://ru.legacy.reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Answer (score 0):

Наконец нашел проблему, а точнее несколько проблем.

1. Спринг просто не мог найти js файлы, так как у меня они лежали не в папке static.
2. При использовании thymeleaf, необходимо было подключать скрипт таким образом:

```
<script th:src="@{some_component.js}"></script>
```